# WordPress author.php template giving 404

Tags: wordpress

I have an `author.php` inside my themes folder. When I try to load an author like `http://vagrant.local/author/admin`, I get a 404. I also tried `http://vagrant.local/author/fname-lname` but got the same result.

Right now my `author.php` only has a static HTML markup and no dynamic data pulling.

I thought I might need to update the Permalink structure, but I do not have the authority to do it.

I am following https://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates but cannot make it to work. What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Generally the best first step is to check/re-save the permalinks for post name `/%postname%/` that's more often than not the cause of the problem. If you can't update that then you'll have to ask someone with admin privileges to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you! I will email him.

Comment: alternativly you can flush_rewrite_rules if you only have FTP access

Comment: @Stender Where should I add this?

Comment: in functions.php you can add this - just delete it after you've used it once : add_action('init', function() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
});

Comment: Thank you! I will try it asap and let you know what I get.

Comment: The code worked fine at my local but when I upload it to remote it does not work. Still showing 404. :( Any suggestion please?